# Maintaining .war artifacts in Jfrog local Artifactory and downloading it for deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, artifactory, continuous-delivery

I am trying to use Artifactory to upload and maintain my artefacts (.war,txt etc) ; currently i want to upload the artifacts through web portal(UI Console) only and download it on specific machine where that .war supposed to be get unwar and run as a application.

I have created the local repository on Artifactory and uploaded one sample file but unable to get download option for this (manually) ; Kindly let me know is managing the self made artifacts through Artifactory (local repo) is correct way of doing the things ? and how to download the uploaded war (artifacts)?

Comment: check my response, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually download a .jar, .war... file from teh Artifactory UI you need to go to:

"Artifact Repository Browser" > "Your Local repository name" > "Rigth click in the artifact" > "Download"

Note: If your artifact is not compressed you can not download it from Artifactory UI.